# Featured Image Length Not Uniform

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have looked up in all my css of theme i am using on my wordpress blog, but problem is when i use featured image on [homepage](http://quotespatio.com) it is not all in same length. how i can make them stretched to fix in unifrom container?
can anyone tell me specific piece of code where i can fix this length?

i saw this line on functions.php in themes.

```
add_image_size('maggie-lite-featured-post', 1170, 350, true); //featured post img size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now you're telling WP to hardcrop, so it's max 1170px width OR 350px height.

To solve this you shoud go for:

```
add_image_size( 'maggie-lite-featured-post', 1170, 9999 );
```

So you tell WP to make it 1170width - the height doesn't matter anymore.

Otherwise you could try to remove the "true" trag from the Crop, but I am not sure if this will also help. But def one of both should be your solution.

```
add_image_size('maggie-lite-featured-post', 1170, 350, false); //featured post img size
```

All the best